# Coaction of a group

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, hopf-algebras, group-actions

Suppose $G$ is a finite group which acts on a $C^*-$algebra which we denote by $A$. I was wondering if there is a naturally induced coaction on $A\otimes C(G)$, here $C(G)$ denotes functions on $G$.
I thank you for the attention and the help.

Comment: Do you mean to write "naturally induced coaction" or something? What do you want to have naturally induced on $A\otimes C(G)$?

Comment: Generally if a group $G$ acts on a ring $A$ then there is a coaction $A\to C(G)\otimes A$. In other words, the dual of the group ring is a Hopf-algebra and coacts on the thing that $A$ acts on.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant "induced coaction".

Comment: If $\alpha: G\times A\to A$ is the action, then $\lambda\mapsto ((g,a)\mapsto\lambda(\alpha(g^{-1},a))$ induces a coaction $A^*\to A^*\otimes C(G)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I would write this is as follows and I would appreciate users calling to attention any errors.

Take a linear action $\Phi:A\times G\rightarrow A$ and extend it to a bilinear map 
$$\Phi_1:A\times \mathbb{C}G\rightarrow A.$$
Now using the universal property we have a linear map
$$\tilde{\Phi}:A\otimes \mathbb{C}G\rightarrow A.$$
Now take the dual of this map:
$$\tilde{\Phi}^*:A^*\rightarrow(A\otimes \mathbb{C}G)^*\cong A^*\otimes \mathbb{C}G^*\cong A^*\otimes C(G),$$
and $\tilde{\Phi}^*$ is a coaction on $A^*$.

I *think* you can also do the following to induce a coaction on $A$ rather than its dual. If the linear action is given by a matrix
$$\Phi(a,g)=\rho(g^{-1})(a),$$
for a $\rho: G\rightarrow \hom(A)$, then we have that
$$\kappa_\Phi(a)=\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)a\otimes\mathbb{1}_{\{g\}},$$
is a coaction $\kappa_{\Phi}:A\to A\otimes C(G)$. I do believe this works but am open to correction on that. Is it as natural as $\tilde{\Phi}^*$?

Comment: For the last part - just note that: (1) $A\otimes C(G)$ is identifiable with $A^G$; (2) maps $G\times A\to A$ are identifiable with maps $A\to A^G$; (3) under these identifications, actions of $G$ in (2) correspond to coactions of $C(G)$ whose coalgebra structure is reflected in (1) via the map $A^G\to A^{G\times G}$ induced by the group multiplication $G\times G\to G$.

Comment: @ Jp McCarthy: Thank you very much the answer.